# Is there an emacs command to go to end of code line (before line comment and whitespaces start)

Tags: comment, motion

say you have that:

```
stuff
    indented stuff   # commented stuff
```

We already got `move-beginning-of-line` and `back-to-indentation` for the left side. Now, for the right side...

I'd love to know if you are aware of a function that goes at the end of the code line (square position)

```
stuff
    indented stuff□   # commented stuff
```

should be able to understand the comment symbol depending on mode I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package [mwim](https://github.com/alezost/mwim.el) offers this functionality. By setting

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-e") 'mwim-end)
```

you get behavior similar to what you described. The package also offers the corresponding `mwim-beginning` command which you can add using

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-a") 'mwim-beginning)
```

See the package [README](https://github.com/alezost/mwim.el) for more.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quick command, lightly tested, that does what you're looking for.

```elisp
(defun eol-dwim ()
  "Go to the end of the line, ignoring comments and trailing
whitespace."
  (interactive)
  (let ((bol (line-beginning-position 1))
        (eol (line-end-position 1)))
    (if (condition-case nil
            (comment-search-forward eol)
          (error nil))
        (re-search-backward comment-start bol nil)
      (end-of-line 1))
    (skip-syntax-backward " " bol)))
```